# Update freezes after upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

Yesterday I upgraded to new Ubuntu version (18.04.1), a few odd things were broken but they are sorted out now. Today I get a security update. I click on the button to accept it. The "discover" window opens and after a longish time displays 3 packages (note: the update button said there were 4), and then nothing... No asking for password, just sitting there, I can't even close the window.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ok I forced the upgrade using aptitude and searching for the packages directly. libgd3 was actually two packages so that explains the 3 vs 4 discrepancy.
Then I 'sudo kill -9 "pid of plasma-discover"' to get rid of the frozen window. But I don't really want to do that everytime there is a security upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrades I got today were:

```
Upgrade: libservlet3.1-java:amd64 (8.5.30-1ubuntu1.3, 8.5.30-1ubuntu1.4), 
         intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20180425.1~ubuntu0.18.04.2, 3.20180807a.0ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
         libgd3:amd64 (2.2.5-4, 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.2)
```

Because the `Discover` route is still a work in progress and there are [reports of difficulties](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/99jfb5/every_new_install_of_kubuntu_1804_freezes_up_when/), I prefer the terminal. I get my clue from the "update" icon that appears in my panel and then open a terminal for the safer, in my opinion, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Discover is fine for installing new software though even that is quicker from the command-line.

Comment: It used to work just fine on the previous distro, so it's a bit disappointing that it failed on the newer one. But now that I know I'll do it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, in Kubuntu 18.04 Discover doesn't ask for password and it freezes, it happens in my computer but in my laptop everything runs smoothly.

The solution I've made is to use the Synaptic Package Manager to update or using the terminal if I'm working with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for the password bug in Discover. In **System Settings** -> *Window Management* -> *Window Behaviour* -> *Advanced* unselect "*Hide utility windows for inactive applications*"

[image: Screenshot]